# SQL Server returns "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the total of the column 'Item Sold', but it is giving me the error, is it the right query? What could be the correct query?

```
SELECT m.m_name as 'Food Item', SUM(od.od_quantity*m.m_price) as 'Items Sold', 
       Sum(Sum(od.od_quantity*m.m_price)) as 'Total' 
FROM orderDetails od left join 
     menu m 
     on od.od_menuID=m.m_id left join 
     orders o 
     on od.od_id=o.o_id 
WHERE o_date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())  and   
      o_date <= getdate() 
group by m.m_name,m.m_price 
order by SUM(od.od_quantity) DESC
```

Comment: Why `Sum(Sum(...))`?

Comment: Then how can i add the column? Is there any other query?

Comment: PLease add some sample Data and the expected result

Comment: @Junaid, what is your expected result of `SUM(SUM`?  It doesn't make sense to aggregate the same values twice. The data and expected results will clarify your question so the query can be constructed properly.

Comment: The subquery should start with `select SUM(....)`

Comment: Why do you group by m.m_price?

Comment: @DanGuzman I want the column Item Sold total to be counted and Display in Sum(Sum) Column. Is there any query?

Comment: @Vad1m To multiply quantity by price, if not be group by, it shows invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
error

Comment: There are [quite a few possible duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+perform+an+aggregate+function+on+an+expression+containing+an+aggregate+or+a+subquery&mixed=0) on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use ROLLUP instead of sum(sum()). And 'Items sold' must not be calculated via multiplying quantity an price:

```
SELECT m.m_name as 'Food Item', SUM(od.od_quantity) as 'Items_Sold', 
       SUM(od.od_quantity*m.m_price) as 'Value_Sold'
FROM orderDetails od 
     left join menu m on od.od_menuID=m.m_id 
     left join orders o on od.od_id=o.o_id 
WHERE o_date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())  and   
      o_date <= getdate() 
group by rollup(m.m_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE` with window function :

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT m.m_name as 'Food Item', SUM(od.od_quantity*m.m_price) as ItemsSold
     FROM orderDetails od left join 
          menu m 
          on od.od_menuID=m.m_id left join 
          orders o 
          on od.od_id=o.o_id 
     WHERE o_date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())  and   
           o_date <= getdate() 
     GROUP BY m.m_name -- Use Non aggregated columns 
)
SELECT m_name, ItemsSold, SUM(ItemsSold) OVER (PARTITION BY m_name) AS Total
FROM cte c;
```

Other option would be to use `rollup` :

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.m_name, 'Total') as 'Food Item', 
       SUM(od.od_quantity) AS ItemsSold,
       SUM(od.od_quantity*m.m_price) as Total
FROM orderDetails od left join 
     menu m 
     on od.od_menuID=m.m_id left join 
     orders o 
     on od.od_id=o.o_id 
WHERE o_date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())  and   
      o_date <= getdate() 
GROUP BY m.m_name WITH ROLLUP; -- Use Non aggregated columns
```

Comment: Would it not be best to find a duplicate for this question? There [appear to be a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+perform+an+aggregate+function+on+an+expression+containing+an+aggregate+or+a+subquery&mixed=0).